# My "too chatty" flags keep getting declined. Why?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I flagged three comments made by the same user at different times, and all three flags got declined (here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489129/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-additional-dependencies-for-custom-build-in/24146532?noredirect=1#comment37281979_24146532) to the most recent one; the original comment had an all-caps expletive, but it got edited out within five minutes). It is quite clear to me that the comment sequence from that user, starting with his ridiculous allegation of plagiarism, and ending in a disgruntled rant and allegations of chain voting, is not overly constructive <sup>*</sup>. However, since my three flags have been declined, I am starting to suspect that these comments do not meet the definition of "too chatty". I looked for a precise definition in the FAQs, but I did not spot one.

So here is my question: why were my "too chatty" flags considered wrong?

<sup>*</sup> I think that the initial comment was 100% fair game, even though I disagree with what it says.

Comment: I'd have gone for "not constructive". I know that doesn't answer your question of course, but still. =D

Comment: The comment chain and taking note of that fact that the individual in question was the one who gave the other answer, all I can say is that it's not worth it.  You might have heard a famous saying: _Never wrestle with a pig.  Both of you get dirty, but the pig enjoys it._

Comment: @devnull Coffee, all over my screen. I hate you. :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260202/upvoting-each-other-to-earn-points-with-a-copied-answer

Comment: @devnull Also _"Never argue with a fool, for he is doing the same"_

Comment: @JimGarrison Have a pity on J. Steen's screen :)

Comment: Yeah, that person already complained in a previous meta post about your better answer. Doesn't seem to understand it...

Comment: I think this comment thread is getting too chatty :D

Comment: @pythonian29033 I agree, there's no discussion tag on this question

Comment: @devnull have you ever tried wrestling a pig? They very much do NOT like it. lol

Comment: @RUJordan Never been one.  Can't say if they do NOT like it.  I'd imagine that they definitely would.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This was a mistake on my part when I was processing the flags. Sorry about that, I've now cleaned them up.

Comment: It looks like the author of the comments has noticed the deletion, and decided to ["restore the justice"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489129/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-additional-dependencies-for-custom-build-in/24146532?noredirect=1#comment37296736_24146532) :-(

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've cleaned up the comments again and left a comment requesting they stop.